# Intra EU Mobility - transfer residence permit from one member State to another

Tags: germany, resident-permit, netherlands, blue-card

**Background:**

I am a non-EU citizen. I have completed my master studies from a recognised German University and later worked in Germany for 3 years. Among the 3 years of work permit visa in Germany, I had Blue card for 18 months. And I possess German B1 level language skills certificate (TELC).

Last year in November I moved to Netherlands to work for a Dutch Company. I therefore terminated my German Blue card and obtained a new blue card in Netherlands.

In summer  I lost my job in the Netherlands. Now I have a job offer from a German company which satisfies the Blue card salary requirement. So, I want to move back to Germany and reapply for Blue card in Germany.

**My question is :
With Dutch residence permit can I move to Germany and apply for blue card at the local foreign office in Germany. Or do I need to first apply for German temporary entry visa from Netherlands. And once I have this temporary visa then only I can move to Germany and apply for Blue card?**

This [article](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/doc_centre/immigration/docs/studies/emn-synthesis_report_intra_eu_mobility_final_july_2013.pdf?fbclid=IwAR2_dgUWXgYI-zGeryLj-uHnVmYT252Dknu50zXp0f5ChINldCLtLa5j-mM) states- " *in Germany, third-country nationals who hold a long-term residence permit in another Member State and who demonstrate adequate means of subsistence and health insurance are entitled to a German long-term residence permit without the need for further verification that the conditions of recognising the long-term resident status were met in the first Member State*" - read last line on page 23.

Comment: Since you seem to have a **Blue-Card** (not a  [EU long-term residence permit, §9a AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0146)) , the rules for the **EU long-term residence permit** will not apply.

Comment: But does the line refer to EU long-term residence permit or long-term residence permit in another Member state ? It is misleading

Comment: The quoted pdf refers to the Directive 2003/109/EG in the context of long term residence permit, so I assume **EU long-term residence permit** is what is meant.